# Iterate a dictionary and store value in array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary `[{'abc':10,'efg':20,'def':30},{'abc':40,'xya':20,'def':50}]` and I would like to create an array `abc[]` and store corresponding value in that array.so the output should look like

```
abc[10,40]
def[30,50]
efg[20]
```

and so on, using python.

Comment: So you want the name of the resulting arrays to be the dict key. Correct?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issue did you run into while trying to implement your solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Any exact solution is probably going to involve exec() or something stranger and most Python programmers would probably encourage you to instead change your list of dictionaries into a dictionary of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'abc':10,'efg':20,'def':30},
    {'abc':40,'xya':20,'def':50},
]

dictionary_of_lists = defaultdict(list)

# there's probably some clever one liner to do this but let's keep
# it simple and clear what's going when we make the transfer:

for dictionary in list_of_dictionaries:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        dictionary_of_lists[key].append(value)

# We've achieved the goal, now just dump dictionary_of_lists to prove it:

for key, value in dictionary_of_lists.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Which outputs:

```
xya [20]
def [30, 50]
abc [10, 40]
efg [20]
```

Not exactly what you asked for but should be, for most purposes, what you need.